# Encontrar números menores en las columnas de una matriz 3x3

Tags: java, matrices

estoy intentando realizar un programa en Java en el cual se crea una matriz 3x3 y debo recorrer las columnas de la matriz e imprimir cual es el numero menor de cada columna, he intentado de varias formas pero nada, lo que tengo hasta el momento es la matriz.

```
    int[][] matriz = { { 1, 4, 3 }, { 5, 2, 4 }, { 7, 4, 2 } };     
    for (int x = 0; x < matriz.length; x++) { //Columnas
        for (int y = 0; y < matriz[x].length; y++) { //Filas
            System.out.print(matriz[x][y] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
```

Les agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Hola Jorge, debe crear una variable auxiliar que vaya guardadando el menor número encontrado, y por cada número ir comparandolo, si es menor al que esta en la variable se reemplaza y al finalizar el el for interno se imprime la variable.

Comment: Ya logre encontrar el numero menor de la primera columna pero no logro pasar a la segunda y tercera columna les agradecería alguna ayuda.

int[][] matriz = { { 3, 2, 7 }, { 2, 5, 3 }, { 5, 1, 5 } };
int numInicial = matriz[0][0];
int posColum = 0;
int posRow = 0;
 for (int colum = posColum; colum < matriz.length; colum++) { // Columnas
  int posNext = matriz[0][colum];
  if (numInicial > posNext) {
   numInicial = posNext;
   posRow++;
  }
  posColum++;
 }
System.out.println("El minimo es " + numInicial);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo el siguiente código que realmente es muy parecido al tuyo, ya casi lo tenías, sólo estaban un poco mezclados los límites de iteración y la cuenta de los valores mínimos. Los comentarios en el código creo que lo explican bien, creo que sería redundante agregar una explicación aparte, así que a continuación te dejo el código:

```
int[][] matriz = {
        { 1, 4, 3 },
        { 5, 2, 4 },
        { 7, 4, 2 }
};

int menor = 0;
int numero = 0;

int nFilas = matriz.length;
int nColumnas = matriz[0].length; // las filas de cada matriz deben ser de igual tamaño, si no no sería matriz
// por ello no es necesario ocupar matriz[x].length

for (int x = 0; x < nColumnas; x++) { // recorrer todas las columnas
    menor = matriz[0][x]; // elegir el primer número de cada columna

    for (int y = 0; y < nFilas; y++) { // recorrer todas las filas
        numero = matriz[y][x]; // elegir el número "y" de la columna "x"
        if (numero < menor)
            menor = numero;
    }
    System.out.println("El número menor de la columna " + (x + 1) + " es " + menor);
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

Benjamin muchas gracias por tu ayuda, tu comentario es la respuesta, solo le agrego algo mas al código al momento de imprimirlo por si alguien lo necesita.

```
    int[][] matriz = { { 1, 4, 3 }, { 5, 2, 4 }, { 7, 4, 2 } };

    int menor = 0;
    int numero = 0;
    int[] numMenores = new int[3]; //Array que guarda lo numeros menores de cada columna, depende mucho de la dimension de la matriz

    int nFilas = matriz.length;
    int nColumnas = matriz[0].length; // las filas de cada matriz deben ser de igual tamaño, si no no sería matriz
    // por ello no es necesario ocupar matriz[x].length

    for (int x = 0; x < nColumnas; x++) { // recorrer todas las columnas
        menor = matriz[0][x]; // elegir el primer número de cada columna

        for (int y = 0; y < nFilas; y++) { // recorrer todas las filas
            numero = matriz[y][x]; // elegir el número "y" de la columna "x"
            if (numero < menor)
                menor = numero;
        }
        numMenores[x] = menor; //Se asigna el numero menor a cada ubicacion en el array.
    }
    //Ciclo para imprimir los numeros menores de cada matriz en una sola linea, 
    //esta parte se modifica dependiendo de como lo quieren mostrar
    for (int i = 0; i < numMenores.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(numMenores[i] + " ");          
    }
```